# How to prevent Visual Studio from adding SAK to prj files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I want the following gone from my prj files:

```
  <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
```

I am using Source Control Explorer only and do not want bindings metadata in my prj and sln files.

No matter what I do, I have removed all bindings via File -> Source Control -> Advanced - Change Source Control, and manually removed all SCC stuff from prj and sln files, Visual Studio keeps altering my prj files and sln file when opening the solution.

Part of the solution might involve altering the Registry, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\SourceControl
AlwaysAddProjectsLocatedOutsideOfSolutionTree changing that zero stopped 18 of 28 prjs from getting auto updated with SCC stuff with opening the solution.

Another thing I tried was to prevent Visual Studio from reloading the sln and prj files after removing all bindings. Visual Studio will detected edits to your sln and prjs and attempt to reload, including on checkin if any kind of automerge was executed.

A part of the solution for me was that when I removed bindings on sln, TFS would all of the sudden treat my sln as not the latest. So when I would commit my clean sln without scc bindings, an automerge would occur bringing back my scc bindings that were part of the latest on the TFS server.

So part of my attempted solution was to use Notepad to edit my sln, ignore any prompts to reload by Visual Studio,  and also Checkout for edit in source control explorer until TFS again recognized my work space version to have the latest sln. Checkout for edit did not work the first time to treat my sln as the latest in my workspace version but the second time it did.

So this worked at first, all solution bindings were removed, until I added an existing project, which was part of the solution before and did have Scc information in it, and that added source control bindings back to the sln file and other related projects.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to keep them at the moment. Maybe in TFS 2014 / ASP.Net vNext (I'm thinking of the Project JSON files) it can be gone. They seem pointless, but I think VS needs them.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well all I can say is that it is nasty. Part of the solution was to prevent Visual Studio from reloading your sln and prj files after removing all bindings. Visual Studio will detected edits to your sln and prjs and attempt to reload, including on checkin if any kind of automerge was executed.

Part of the solution might involve altering the Registry, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\SourceControl AlwaysAddProjectsLocatedOutsideOfSolutionTree changing that zero stopped 18 of 28 prjs from getting auto updated with SCC stuff with opening the solution.

A part of the solution for me was that when I removed bindings on sln, TFS would all of the sudden treat my sln as not the latest. So when I would commit my clean sln without scc bindings, an automerge would occur bringing back my scc bindings that were part of the latest on the TFS server.

So part of my solution was to use Notepad to edit my sln, ignore any prompts to reload by Visual Studio,  and also Checkout for edit in source control explorer until TFS again recognized my work space version to have the latest sln. Checkout for edit did not work the first time to treat my sln as the latest in my workspace version but the second time it did.

After that and this is where the most important and straight forward part of the solution lies. Remove all bindings, you might have already done that, Save All. Now change your Source Control plugin to none in Visual Studio options,now close the solution. Now open the SLN in Notepad and make sure there is no SCC stuff. NOW DELETE YOUR solution level .SUO. Open the sln again, you should have no bindings and you should have pending changes to commit for the sln and some or all of your prj files in your Source Control explorer and a warning saying you have no Source Control plugin set. Finally, go back Source Control options and set Team Foundation Server as your source control. Commit the sln and prj files with all SCC stuff removed.